# How do I calculate average of last 10 scores from a row containing blanks

Tags: microsoft-excel

Trying to do a similar calculation as Larry Burge Jr regarding calculating handicaps.

I was unable to get his formula to work as I have a slightly different scenario. Trying to calculate a running average of Stableford Points.

[image]

Any help editing the formula below (which calculates -23 in BQ4) to get it to show the 25 in B4 (actual average of last 10 scores) would be much appreciated.

```
=ROUND((AVERAGE(OFFSET(F4,0,LARGE(IF(F4:BP4>0,COLUMN(F4:BP4),""),10)-COLUMN(F4),1,COLUMN(BP4)+1-LARGE(IF(F4:BP4>0,COLUMN(F4:BP4),""),10)))-54)*0.8,0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Say we have data from **A1** through **Z1**.  There may be blanks anywhere in that first row.

In **Z2** enter:

```
=IF(Z1="","",Z1)
```

In **Y2** enter:

```
=IF(Y1="","",IF(COUNT($Z$2:Z2)>9,"",Y1))
```

then copy **Y2** to **A2** through **X2**.  Then in another cell enter:

```
=AVERAGE(2:2)
```

[image]

NOTE:

1. if there are less than ten items in the first row, you get the average of what's there.
2. This method avoids both array formulas and volatile functions.

Comment: Plugged in your formula but it doesn't pull the last 10 scores, just an average of all numbers entered between a1 and z1. Thanks for your help though as I can use your information in other areas of my work.